# (latitude, longitude) Create a bounding box from a radius

Tags: java, coordinates, box, radius, bounding

The f I have one pair of latitude and longitude and a radius

How can I create a box around this pair based on the radius?

Comment: If coordinates are (x,y) and radius is r then one simple bounding box can be formed from 4 points (x - r, y - r) (x + r, y - r), (x - r, y + r), (x + r, y + r).

Comment: Knowing that r is given in km. Is this going to work?

Answer (score -1):

So, supposing that (latitude,longitude) is the center of your circle, the bounding box (square) that contains the circle would have its corners at the following positions:

(latitude-radius,longitude-radius)

(latitude-radius,longitude+radius)

(latitude+radius,longitude+radius)

(latitude+radius,longitude-radius)

Comment: This doesn't take into account the spherical shape of the earth.